# Alamofire - Rest API call with Custom Header

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm working with Swift + Alamofire. I'm consuming a Rest API which returns data in JSON format and I've tested it in Rest API Testing tool i.e. PostMan. Here is it's snapshot and it's working fine

[image: Snapshot from PostMan]

The only thing is Authorization Header in this Get request.But same isn't working in Swift+Alamofire. Here goes the code snippet.

```
let requestHeaders: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Authorization": "bearer " + (Session.user?.accessToken!)!
        ]
Alamofire.request("http://abcabc.com/api/StoreType/Stores", headers: requestHeaders).responseJSON { (response) -> Void in

            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                guard let rawJson = response.result.value as? [String: Any] else {

                    let serverError = NSError(domain: "Server error", code: (response.response?.statusCode)!, userInfo: ["msg": "Received Malformed data from server"])
                    errorBlock(serverError)
                    return
                }

                let formattedJson = JSON(rawJson)
                if (formattedJson["Message"] != JSON.null) {

                    let serverError = NSError(domain: "Server error", code: (response.response?.statusCode)!, userInfo: ["msg": formattedJson["Message"]])
                    errorBlock(serverError)
                } else { // No error case

                    Session.storeCategories = StoreCategory.initializeStoreCategoriesWithStores(storeCategoryList: formattedJson)
                    successBlock(formattedJson)
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                errorBlock(error)
            }
        }
```

But I get following error always. (Snapshot from Xcode)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You response is type of `[[String: Any]]` not `[String: Any]`.

Change this as:

```
guard let rawJson = response.result.value as? [[String: Any]] else {
    let serverError = NSError(domain: "Server error", code: (response.response?.statusCode)!, userInfo: ["msg": "Received Malformed data from server"])
    errorBlock(serverError)
    return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom request object of type `URLRequest` set your `URL`, `Headers` and `RequestType` in your request object then simply ask `Alamofire` to start this request.

```
let requestHeaders: [String: String] = [
            "Authorization": "bearer " + (Session.user?.accessToken!)!
        ]
        if let url = URL(string: "https://www.example.com/someApiURL") {
            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            request.httpMethod = "GET"
            request.headerParam = requestHeaders
            Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON{ (response) -> Void in

            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                guard let rawJson = response.result.value as? [String: Any] else {

                    let serverError = NSError(domain: "Server error", code: (response.response?.statusCode)!, userInfo: ["msg": "Received Malformed data from server"])
                    errorBlock(serverError)
                    return
                }

                let formattedJson = JSON(rawJson)
                if (formattedJson["Message"] != JSON.null) {

                    let serverError = NSError(domain: "Server error", code: (response.response?.statusCode)!, userInfo: ["msg": formattedJson["Message"]])
                    errorBlock(serverError)
                } else { // No error case

                    Session.storeCategories = StoreCategory.initializeStoreCategoriesWithStores(storeCategoryList: formattedJson)
                    successBlock(formattedJson)
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                errorBlock(error)
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, and for response class mapping from json you can use **Codable** or **ObjectMapper**

```
var headers = ["":""]
headers["Authorization"] = "bearer " + (Session.user?.accessToken!)!
   Alamofire.request(baseURL + endpoint,headers: headers)
            .responseArray { (response: DataResponse<[Model]>) in
            print("Response: \(response)")

    }
```